# insert on update statement not inserting data into table

Tags: php, sql

When Submitting Fresh Forms, there is nothing getting inserted into database except app_id. but when we upload image on the existing **appid** its getting updated to database. so insert query is not working for other fields except appid. and update query is working fine here.

```
<?php

session_start();

$appid = $_GET['appid'];

include("connect.php");

if($_POST){

$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        $pptimg =  $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $_SESSION['pptimg'] = $pptimg;
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

}

// Insert record
  $query = "INSERT INTO payments (app_id, pptimg) VALUES('$appid', '$pptimg') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
            app_id='$appid', pptimg='$pptimg'";
  if (mysqli_query($connect,$query)){
    echo "Image were updated successfully.";
    header("Location: preview.php?appid=".$appid);
    }else{
    echo "Photo not uploaded".mysqli_error($connect);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why do you update the DB in case of an error during file upload? Also, please follow this guide when giving code - [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look closely at this part of your code:

```
if($_POST){
   // Many checks here...

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "uploaded";
            $pptimg =  $_FILES["file"]["name"]; // <-- Variable set only here
            $_SESSION['pptimg'] = $pptimg;
        } else {
            echo "didn't upload";
        }
    }
}

// Insert record
$query = "INSERT INTO payments (app_id, pptimg) VALUES('$appid', '$pptimg')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          app_id='$appid', pptimg='$pptimg'";
```

I indented it, removed some lines and simplified others to focus on the structure.

Now, do you see what is happening? **Everytime this script is accessed, you try to insert a record**. But wait - if there's an error? You just print it and go further.

Whether there is an error or not - you are inserting a record. The `$pptimg` variable which you use in the query, though, is set only if the file was uploaded. **In every other case `$pptimg` is not set, and therefore you get this field empty**.

Comment: @AI.G. : Working ! Found Errors.